# When uploading a photo to a website, for custom gifts and the like, do they only access the uploaded photo?

Tags: website-features, photo-gallery, photo, access-control, folder

When uploading a photo to a website for a custom gift that the photo goes on, the phone or computer brings up a window to choose the photo you want. Does the website see any of the photos while you are scrolling to the one you want, or is that the devices internal ‘file explorer’ and the website only sees the chosen photo/file after upload?

Thanks!

Comment: What code does your website use when this is uploaded?

Comment: [Webmasters is a site for asking questions about operating and managing your own website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions about the privacy risks of using a web browser aren't on topic here.

Comment: Sorry about that! Noted for next time.

Answer (score 1):

*Probably* not.  Generally, as you alluded, the computer's file explorer locates the files, you select one and then when you click "submit", or whatever the button is to trigger the upload, *then* the file is sent to the server.

The "probably" is because you have given zero information about the method used to upload.

Imagine the security implications if a webserver could read all files on a local computer when all you are doing is choosing one.

Comment: "Imagine the security implications if a webserver could read all files on a local computer when all you are doing is choosing one." And at the same time, there is "WebUSB API" at https://wicg.github.io/webusb/  from W3C where the abstract is "This document describes an API for securely providing access to Universal Serial Bus devices from web pages.". This goes far further than just reading files... Of course all is in the "securely".